# details list like in explorer.exe

Tags: delphi, list, membership

I am having a problem finding a Delphi component to list items with some information as well just like the Windows file explorer does.

Is there a component that I could use to make a list of names and information about them, like in explorer.exe maybe? I am trying to make a club membership management program so I want to be able to list the name of members and basic info and then when there name is clicked it goes into more detailed info.

If there is a component that can list stuff the way explorer.exe can then please tell me.

Comment: Set `ViewStyle` to `vsReport`, add some `Columns`, add `Items` and `SubItems` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The component which you are looking for is the [TListView](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListView). If your application will be based on a database information you must consider a data aware component like [TDBGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBGrids.TDBGrid)

Comment: I presume @Remy's modification, which makes much sense in context, is lost due to an edit conflict: *"Windows Explorer uses a standard ListView control. In Delphi, that is the `TListView` component."*.

Comment: In my original answer I put which the windows explorer uses  The `SysListView32` class equivalent to the `TListView`, but that affirmation is only valid to windows versions previous to Windows 7 (because that I delete that part of my answer), Now the Explorer in Windows 7 uses a new undocumented class (control) called `DirectUIHWND` instead of the documented "SysListView32" control like all the versions before it.

Comment: @RRUZ: `DirectUIHWND` has been around since XP, and is widely used in Microsoft apps, especially in Windows 7. DirectUI is a high-performance UI framework that separates UI development from business logic development.  It is an undocumented framework, though.